# How can I use the Embedded assets plugin to save assets on the front-end?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-embeddedassets

I am using the [Embedded Assets plugin](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-embedded-assets) to get YouTube videos and its working great within the CP.

I am able to show the asset(s) on my page by using

```
{{ embed.safeHtml|raw }}
```

Which works great. I'm able to see the YT video that was uploaded in the CP. It's *huge* but it is getting rendered.

I would like the user to be able to "upload" videos from the front-end so reading this:

> As embedded assets are stored as JSON files

The instructions above are pretty clear - I just don't "get it". I have clicked the oEmbed page as suggested for more info to see an example json output, but I guess its getting from point A to B is what I'm not sure about.

Do I create a `plainText` field, and have the user paste in a video url? Then my controller method (somehow) creates the json file and saves it somewhere? I'm not sure where/how to start.

I would also like to specify a width on the rendered iframe that is getting generated, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that either.

Thank you for any suggestions!